# How index the same field in multiple ways with wildcard in ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the below mappings for a field ("name"):

```
            "name": {
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
```

It works fine and allows to search as both text and keyword.
As per the ES documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html A string field could be mapped as a text field for full-text search and as a keyword field for sorting or aggregation.

But I am trying to extend this mapping to also support wildcard search.

I tried to modify the mapping(for eg. like below) but couldn't get it working.

```
            "name": {
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
                "type": "text",
                "fields": [{
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "wildcard"
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }]
            }
```

Also tried with,

```
            "name": {
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
                "type": "text",
                "fields": [{
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "wildcard"
                    }
                }, {"raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }}]
            }
```

How should the mapping look like to allow name to be searched as text, keyword and wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to index the `name` field in multiple ways. Modified index mapping will be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "wildcard"
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use `name` for text-based search, `name.raw` for wildcard search, `name.keyword` for keyword search

Comment: @Matt Ryan please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: What if I wanted to map a decimal field as both a double and a text using a standard_analyzer? Would I use a similar solution as to what you have here?